# FB messenger bot: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined

Tags: node.js, facebook, express, facebook-messenger-bot

I am testing my bot from friends Facebook account as I am unable to find the message option on my Facebook page. I am following
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/quick-start
Following is the error Im getting on Heroku Logs

```
    at=info method=POST path="/webhook" host=powerful-anchorage-25620.herokuapp.com request_id=bb2aa329-1bb5-4271-8959-074629468238 fwd="173.252.98.219" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=500 bytes=404 protocol=https
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650181+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read property 'object' of undefined
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650193+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/app.js:33:11
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650195+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650196+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650197+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Route.dispatch (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650198+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650198+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650199+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.process_params (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650200+00:00 app[web.1]:     at next (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650200+00:00 app[web.1]:     at serveStatic (/app/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:75:16)
2017-09-25T07:11:21.650201+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5'
```

Following is in app.js which is hosted on Heroic

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

// views is directory for all template files
//app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
//app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(request, response) {

  console.log("Hello World");
  response.send("Hello World");
});

app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.mode'] === 'subscribe' &&
      req.query['hub.verify_token'] === "test") {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }  
});

app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
  var data = req.body;

  // Make sure this is a page subscription
  if (data.object === 'page') {

    // Iterate over each entry - there may be multiple if batched
    data.entry.forEach(function(entry) {
      var pageID = entry.id;
      var timeOfEvent = entry.time;

      // Iterate over each messaging event
      entry.messaging.forEach(function(event) {
        if (event.message) {
          receivedMessage(event);
        } else {
          console.log("Webhook received unknown event: ", event);
        }
      });
    });

    // Assume all went well.
    //
    // You must send back a 200, within 20 seconds, to let us know
    // you've successfully received the callback. Otherwise, the request
    // will time out and we will keep trying to resend.
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});

function receivedMessage(event) {
  // Putting a stub for now, we'll expand it in the following steps
   var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
  var timeOfMessage = event.timestamp;
  var message = event.message;

  console.log("Received message for user %d and page %d at %d with message:", 
    senderID, recipientID, timeOfMessage);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message));

  var messageId = message.mid;

  var messageText = message.text;
  var messageAttachments = message.attachments;

  if (messageText) {

    // If we receive a text message, check to see if it matches a keyword
    // and send back the example. Otherwise, just echo the text we received.
    switch (messageText) {
      case 'generic':
        sendGenericMessage(senderID);
        break;

      default:
        sendTextMessage(senderID, messageText);
    }
  } else if (messageAttachments) {
    sendTextMessage(senderID, "Message with attachment received");
  }
}

function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: messageText
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      console.log("Successfully sent generic message with id %s to recipient %s", 
        messageId, recipientId);
    } else {
      console.error("Unable to send message.");
      console.error(response);
      console.error(error);
    }
  });  
}

function sendGenericMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
  // To be expanded in later sections
}

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Kindly let me know where am I going wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need the body-parser module, so the `req` isn't being parsed properly. Replace the first two lines with this:

```
const 
  express = require('express'),
  bodyParser = require('body-parser');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({"extended": false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the answer. :)